# Warnings when using Fake.InitializeFixture

Tags: visual-studio, warnings, fakeiteasy

I'm using Fake.InitializeFixture like this:

```
[Fake] private ISomeDependency _someDependency;
[UnderTest] private SomethingToTest _somethingToTest;

[SetUp]
public void SetUp()
{
    Fake.InitializeFixture(this);
}

...
```

It works fine when running the tests, but the problem is that Visual Studio gives me these warnings:

> Warning   27  Field '...._someDependency' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null

I would like to have zero warnings when compiling. Is there any way to get rid of these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two solutions:

1. Make the field non private.
2. Disable that warning in your test project.

Comment: How do I disable that warning for a project? I've only managed to suppress FxCop warnings. I've tried both `/nowarn:649` and `[assembly: SuppressMessage("", "CS0649")]`. `#pragma warning disable 0649` works, but not project wide.

Comment: To disable for the test project open project Properties, go to the Build tab and enter the code 0649 in the Suppress Warnings box.